# Outlook Interop 2010 C# Moving Item to Shared OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail

Tags: c#, interop, outlook

SOmething odd is happening. I'm trying to copy and move and item from a local MAPI folder to a remtoe Sent Items folder using GetSharedDefaultFolder. It works for the inbox folder but not sent items, even though i have permissions to it. Any ideas would be great thank you.

The Error is 'Could not complete the operation. One or more parameter values are not valid'

The code sample is:

```
Outlook.MailItem cItem = (mailmsg as Outlook.MailItem).Copy() as Outlook.MailItem;
Outlook.NameSpace ns = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
//ns.Logon()
Outlook.Recipient recipient = ns.CreateRecipient("realusera@domain.com");
recipient.Resolve();
if (recipient.Resolved)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Resolved user");
    Outlook.MAPIFolder mapifld = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recipient, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
    cItem = (Outlook.MailItem)cItem.Move(mapifld);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to MS documentation on this API, the olFolderSentMail is one of the default folders that is NOT allowed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._namespace.getshareddefaultfolder.aspx

Excerpt:

FolderType can be one of the following OlDefaultFolders constants: olFolderCalendar, olFolderContacts, olFolderDrafts, olFolderInbox, olFolderJournal, olFolderNotes, or olFolderTasks. (The constants olFolderDeletedItems, olFolderOutbox, olFolderJunk, olFolderConflicts, olFolderLocalFailures, olFolderServerFailures, olFolderSyncIssues, olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders, olFolderRssSubscriptions, olFolderToDo, olFolderManagedEmail, and **olFolderSentMail** cannot be specified for this argument.)

Comment: Thanks Mark, I think I figured a few other things out about the Outlook architecture at the same and decide to drop the above as it would never work. GOod to know to official document so thank you

-Steve